# Sorting CHtml::listData dropdown in Yii

Tags: mysql, yii

My database table is named 'status' and it has a column named 'order', which is of type float.

I'm trying to sort the status fields based on order from lowest to greatest and input those fields into a dropdown list.

This is the code I'm using:

```
echo $form->dropDownListRow($my_model, 'status', CHtml::listData(Status::model()->findAll(array('order'=>"'order' ASC")), 'id', 'name'), array('class'=>'span3','prompt'=>Yii::t('forms', 'Please Select A Status')));
```

But the list is always ordered by status ID.  Do I need to do some type casting?  If so, how would I typecast my query so that it orders by 'order' ascending?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified the order incorrectly:

```
array('order'=>"'order' ASC")
```

There are extra quotes around `order` (the column name), which means that in effect you are not sorting at all. Remove the quotes to fix the problem, but put backticks in their place because `order` is a reserved word in MySql:

```
array('order'=>"`order` ASC")
```

Comment: If I don't escape 'order', then I get this error message: `CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order ASC' at line 1. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT * FROM `status` `t` ORDER BY order ASC`

Comment: @ews2001: In hindsight it's obvious that it would error out because "order" is a reserved word in MySql. So you need to put *backticks* around it, just like there are around `status` in this query.